# Creating Razor Class Library with TargetFramework to .net core 3 throws errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-3.0, razor-class-library

I am creating an ASP.Net Core 3 pre-release 9 MVC app and I want to create some Razor Class Libraries (RCL). When creating a RCL from the template it will default to targeting `netstandard2.0` which is indeed not possible for .Net Core 3 anymore referring to the following [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3756#issuecomment-434114175). This then throws some weird errors by the following code:

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[image]

Comment: How did you create RCL? Based on the error message, it seems to be related with `Website.Landing`. Is this the built-in template? Share us detail information about your steps.

Comment: Yea, I created it via the CLI Template.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For creating RCL for MVC, you need to configuring `Support pages and views` like

[image]

For this, it will append `<AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>` in your *.csproj like

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

For above screen shot, it uses VS 2019 Preview.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it indeed works! It is weird that it doesn't tell that anywhere. (I created the RCL via the CLI)

Comment: It seems that it's not required anymore for notecoreapp3.1